# Scrollspy não está funcionando

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um site, e a principio está tudo funcionando, porém o Scrollspy(Bootstrap 3.3) não está funcionando, segui diversos tutoriais na internet de como aplica-lo em um Website mas não obtive sucesso mesmo seguindo-os corretamente. Eis um trecho de meu código.

```css
html, body { 
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 text-shadow:none;
 background:#FFF !important;
 position: relative;
}

.links-navbar{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px;
}
.links-navbar a {
 padding: 25px 36px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar .links-navbar a:hover,
.navbar .links-navbar>.active>a,
.navbar .links-navbar a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 20;
 color: var(--hoverLink);
 background-color: var(--hoverFundo);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="logos" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:35px;">
          <a href="https://dalposso.com.br" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/dalposso-logo.png" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:35px;">
          <a href="index.php">
            <img src="images/murano-logo.png" style="width: 100%;">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding-top: 90px;">
          <a href="https://dalposso.com.br" class="link-dalposso">
            Voltar para o site
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navegacao" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:50px; padding: 0; z-index: 20;">
        <div class="links-navbar nav">
          <a href="#emprendimento">o emprendimento</a>
          <a href="#areas">áreas comuns</a>
          <a href="#garagens">garagens</a>
          <a href="#apartamentos">apartamentos</a>
          <a href="#localizacao">localizacao</a>
          <a href="#contato">contato</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara para o ScrollSpy funciona vc precisa seguir as regras estabelecidas pela documentação oficial que vc pode consultar aqui! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#scrollspy

**Ponto 1:** Não sei se vc está usando `position:relative` no `<body>`, mas isso é necessário para o ScrollSpy funcionar!

**Ponto 2:**

> **Requires Bootstrap nav** 
>   Scrollspy currently requires the use of a
>   Bootstrap nav component for proper highlighting of active links.

Resumindo: *"Vc precisa usar o componente **Bootstrap nav** para ativar a marcação dos links"* ou seja vc tem que usar a NavBar oficial do Bootstrap e a sua que vc colocou na pergunta está totalmente diferente da NavBar original do BS3 como vc pode ver aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui deixo um exemplo simples funcionando do ScrollSpy para vc usar como referência, repare no position:relative no Body, no link entre os `href` do menu e nos `id` das `sections` e ***principalmente na construção da NavBar***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
        }

        #section1, 
        #section2, 
        #section3  {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1E88E5;
        }
        #section2 {
            background-color: #673ab7;
        }
        #section3 {
            background-color: #ff9800;
        }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, 
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at
            the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at
            the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at
            the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at
            the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at
            the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at
            the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**OBS:** Deixei no CSS os estilos que vc precisa customizar para quando o item da Navbar estiver `.active`

Comment: Ele está com position relative no body, segui todas as instruções pelas quais você mencionou como o Nav do bootstrap porém não obtive sucesso . Faltou alguma coisa? 
Assim como tentei trocar aquela div do .links-navbar por uma <ul>, com cada link sendo uma <li>.

Comment: @aleque_b cara edita novamente a sua pergunta e coloca o código completo da sua página, da mesma forma que eu fiz na minha resposta, coloca tudo que tiver entre as tags HTML e o seu CSS também. Pois se vc analisar o exemplo vc vai ver que ele funciona, então provavelmente é alguma coisa que vc fez, ou deixou de fazer na estrutura que está bugando o Spy

Comment: Sim eu editei e o HTML está conforme postado agora, nao postei o código inteiro porque ele está mesclando HTML, CSS e PHP. Mas assim, todas as âncoras estão configuradas, assim como as Divs com Id. Não tem o que pode estar de errado.
Mas mesmo assim não está funcionando.

Comment: @aleque_b Cara a sua Navbar ainda continua completamente diferente do modelo do Bootstrap padrão.... Olha na minha resposta  como está a minha `<nav></nav>` vc está construindo sua Navbar dentro dessa div `<div class="links-navbar nav">` isso está totalmente diferente do que diz a documentação.... Cara pega o modelo que eu postei e "reconstroi" a sua página dentro dele, acho que é uma opção pra vc já que não está rolando com o seu código.

Comment: Refiz o cabeçalho do 0 e parece que agora funcionou. Desculpe a demora pela resposta, tive que reformar tudo o CSS para estar estilizado de acordo como tava no cabeçalho anterior. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @aleque_b tranquilo jovem esses componentes são chatos de mexer mesmo, tem que seguir a documentação a risca para funcionar direito, qualquer ordem diferente nas tags html, ou uma classe css a menos o componente já para de funcionar, mas que bom que deu certo, boa sorte ai com o projeto e... "leia a documentação" rss. []´s